# Useing a nested if in a make file

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to add a conditional statement to my makefile to select a set of configuration files based on an input variable and process them using an external bash script but I can't get it to work. I'm on a unix platform and this is the section of my make file:

```
package:
    
        @echo Making Package
        @if [ $(PRODUCT) == PROD_1 ]; then\
        @echo configure PROD_1;\
        ./$(CONFIG_AREA)/copier.sh $(CONFIG_AREA)/Prod1_configuration $(STAGING_AREA);\
        else\
        @if [ $(PRODUCT) == PROD_2 ]; then\
        @echo configure PROD_2;\
        ./$(CONFIG_AREA)/copier.sh $(CONFIG_AREA)/Prod2_configuration $(STAGING_AREA);\
        fi;\
        fi
        -@cp $(STAGING_ZIP_AREA)/version.txt $(STAGING_AREA)
```

The `copier.sh` script takes in two arguments, a source directory and a destination directory. I get the following error:

```
Making Package
/bin/sh: -c: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/sh: -c: line 7: `fi;\'
```

Comment: I should have said makefiles are a bit of a dark art to me sorry

Comment: First, please edit your question and put the error message into a code block.  It's not understandable (as should be obvious if you check your question via the preview before posting it, or re-read it after posting it).  Take out all the "internal" `@` signs.  These are tokens that make understands, not the shell, and it only looks for them as the first characters in a script.  When you use a backslash at the end of a line it concatenates the next line so it's not a different line anymore as far as make is concerned.

Comment: Never use `@` in your recipes until you're sure they are working correctly -- and even then consider not doing so.  Having joined multiple physical lines into one logical recipe line, if you want to suppress echo for that then it should be with one `@` at the beginning of the logical line.  Any others are passed through to the shell.

Comment: Next you can't use `==` in a shell script, portably.  The POSIX standard for the `test` program uses `=` for equality not `==`.  Some shells allow `==` as an extension but, as above, it's not portable.  Finally check your makefile carefully to ensure there are no spaces after any of the backslashes.  You need the backslash to escape the newline, not a space, so the backslash must be the final character on the line to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for the responses I've changed it completely having discovered another post to be:

```
ifeq ($(PRODUCT),PROD_1)
    @echo "PROD_1 Configuration"
    $(CONFIG_AREA)/copier.sh $(CONFIG_AREA)/Prod1_configuration $(STAGING_AREA)
else
    ifeq ($(PRODUCT),PROD_2)
        @echo "PROD_2 Configuration"
        $(CONFIG_AREA)/copier.sh $(CONFIG_AREA)/Prod2_configuration $(STAGING_AREA)
    endif
endif
```

note that ifeq, else and endif are indented with spaces not TABs as TABs don't work but TAB indents in between them.